# $g$ not continuous in $(0,0)$, differentiable in every direction AND $|D_vg(x)| \leq |v|$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have found plenty of simliar questions to mine, but in this case there is one more condition that needs to be satisfied, this is the problem:

"Find a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, so that all directional derivatives $D_v g(x)$ exist ($v\in\mathbb{R}^2$) but $g$ isn't continuous in $(0,0)$ AND $|D_vg(x)| \leq |v|$."

It's easy to find a function that satisfies the first two conditions, but I just don't know how to use the third one. I also have a problem in understanding it. For example, I can have 2 vectors which point in the same direction but have different length, for example:

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0.01\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right)$, both point into the same direction, but their length isn't the same. With this in mind, $|v|$ can become arbitrary small, meaning that  $|D_vg(x)|$ has to be $0$, so $g$ has to be a constant function. But that doesn't really help, since there is no constant function that is uncontinuous in $(0,0)$ (or is there?), so I guess that I didn't understand the $|D_vg(x)| \leq |v|$ condition properly.

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Are you sure you can have a function discontinuous at (0,0) for which all directional derivatives (including that at (0,0)) exist?  Maybe you mean $\nabla g$ is discontinuous.  I hope I am not being slow here.

Comment: @WADon Consider $g$ defined by $(r,\theta) \mapsto \sin^2\theta$  for $r>0$ and $g(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Neal - isn't your function discontinuous at the origin?  Approaching the origin along the positive $ y $ axis, there is a discontinuity as the function has value 1 for $ r > 0 $ and zero at (0,0).  Being discontinuous, it has no directional derivative.  It seems to me that if every directional derivative exists, then $ f(x+\delta x, y+\delta y) \to f(x,y) $ regardless of the manner $ \delta x, \delta y \to 0 $.

Comment: @WADon Thanks, you caught an error in my example -- by your point, a function with directional derivatives must be continuous on every line from the origin. But you can have functions that are continuous on all lines through the origin but discontinuous along some other path. For example the function given here as a counterexample: https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_in_every_linear_direction_not_implies_continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $|D_vg| \leq |v|$ is really a constraint on $g$ as the angle of $v$ varies.

Your observation that $|D_vg|$ has to go to zero as $|v|\to 0$ is correct but not really relevant here. In fact $|D_vg|$ is always proportional to $|v|$. As you scale $v$, the proportionality constant will stay the same. (In some sense the "real" directional derivative of $g$ is the ratio $|D_vg|/|v|$.)

Requiring that $|D_vg|\leq |v|$ says that proportionality constant must always be less than $1$. As the angle of $v$ varies, the slope of $g$ along the line $vt$ can't increase without bound -- for example, $g(r,\theta) = r^{1/(1+2\sin^2\theta)}$ does not meet this condition, since along the line $\theta = \pi/2$ the function behaves like a cube root.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x,y\in \mathbb R^2.$ Define $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ to be the function $f(t)= g(x+t(y-x)).$ Then $f'(t) = D_{y-x}g(x+t(y-x))$ for all $t.$ By the MVT, $f(1)-f(0) = f'(c)$ for some $c\in (0,1).$ It follows that

$$|g(y)-g(x)|=|f(1)-f(0)| = |f'(c)| = |D_{y-x}g(x+c(y-x))|\le |y-x|.$$

Thus $g$ is Lipschitz on $\mathbb R^2,$ so is certainly continuous everywhere.